# Finding common values of array field of two documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two documents in Elastic search with the following values

```
uid  preferences
1    [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,100]
2    [20,70,30,100,1000,77,45]
```

Is there any way we can do array intersect on preferences for these two records and get the result `[20,70,30,100]` ? Currently we are getting these two records to app server and doing intersect  , but wanted to check if there is any direct way of getting the intersect values from Elasticsearch directly .Thank You .

Comment: Intersect values per what? Per a group of document IDs? Or just a pair of 2 like in your example?

Comment: Thank you @JoeSorocin for your comment . Pair of 2 like mentioned in the example is fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd solve this using a parameterized [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html). Here's a more readable version:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "id": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "preferences_intersection": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.shared_vals = [];",
        "map_script": "state.shared_vals.addAll(new ArrayList(doc['preferences']));",
        "combine_script": """
          return state.shared_vals.stream()
                                  .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(state.shared_vals, i) >= params.compared_docs_count)
                                  .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))
        """,
        "reduce_script": "return states[0]",
        "params": {
          "compared_docs_count": 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how the `terms` query was applied along with `params.compared_docs_count` so we can check the # of occurrences of the common values.

Here's the compact version of the query without triple quotes:

```
{"size":0,"query":{"terms":{"id":[1,2]}},"aggs":{"preferences_intersection":{"scripted_metric":{"init_script":"state.shared_vals = [];","map_script":"state.shared_vals.addAll(new ArrayList(doc['preferences']));","combine_script":"          return state.shared_vals.stream()\n                                  .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(state.shared_vals, i) >= params.compared_docs_count)\n                                  .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2))\n                                  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))","reduce_script":"return states[0]","params":{"compared_docs_count":2}}}}}
```

Comment: Thank You @JoeSorocin for your answer . Since it is a script based thinking of performance issues. Good luck for your "Elasticsearch handbook"

Comment: Thanks! Yea scripts tend to be slow but it in this one we're only going through 2 docs thanks to the `terms` query so I wouldn't worry about it.